# Pass string with AJAX and find in database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm passing a string with AJAX and trying to find the mySQL db entry that contains the string in one of its columns. I think the string passing is OK but perhaps the mySQL code is incorrect?

```
$id = ($_POST['video_id']);

$text_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `wmtwDB` WHERE `url` LIKE (" . $id . ") LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: Perhaps it is perhaps it is not. Who knows?

Comment: 1. mysql_ libraries deprecated. 2. SQL injection possible 3. Check test_result is false, if so print the error

Comment: also, why the hell are you using `LIKE` there ?!

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: I agree with tereško, an ID is unique, or at least should be. A `LIKE` is to be used for finding similar results. You should also use the wildcards in a LIKE. 

%URL is Ends with
URL% is Begins with
%URL% is Contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LIKE syntax is failing. Try with:

```
$text_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `wmtwDB` WHERE `url` LIKE %" . $id . "% LIMIT 1");
```